# Latency in publisher/subscriber

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

In a somewhat big project i'm working on, I'm stubbling on an issue.
I have 2 nodes, one focus on perception and the other one generating speed control order for a UR10 robot. The perception node subscribe on UR10 controller current position topic, do some data treatment, forward it to the node in charge of control. Issue is : perception node receive and update position close to real time. Subscriber to perception is called at the right frequency. Data received is old. First thing coming to mind is queue size too big. I updated all my queue to be sized 1, still have the issue. Anyone got a lead?
Ros version is Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372840/latency-in-publisher/subscriber/) by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2021-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mistake on my side. Perception receive faulty data, will investigate the robot controller.

---

Originally posted by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) with karma: 71 on 2021-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0